# Problem with deadlock waiting for REST call to finish while sending several requests concurrently

Tags: c#, asynchronous, concurrency

I have the following situation. I have a class that iterates through a collection which contains a list of requests that need to be serviced by some REST API. The responses are then processed by another class and returned. The top class will wait for all the requests to finish processing before continuing execution.

## Top class

```
var results = new BlockingCollection<string>();

Task.WaitAll(requests.Select(request => Task.Run(() =>
{
    var payload = new MyRequest()
    {
        ParameterOne = request.FieldOne,
        ...
    };

    var partialResult = this.RequestProcessingUtility.Service(payload);
    results.Add(partialResult.Result);
})).ToArray());

// continues...
```

## RequestProcessingUtility

```
public Result Convert(MyRequest request)
{
    var result = new Result();
    var response = this.RestUtility.Execute<Response, Request>(uri, HttpMethod.Get, request);

    // processes response into result

    return result;
}
```

## RetsUtility

```
public RestResult<TResult> Execute<TResult, TRequest>(string uri, HttpMethod method, TRequest request)
    where TResult : class
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = null;
    var message = this.CreateRequest(uri, method, request);

    try
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                response = HttpClient.SendAsync(message, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead).Result;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                throw exception;
            }
        })
        .Wait();
    }
    catch (AggregateException taskException)
    {
        // ... something
    }

    return this.ProcessResult<TResult>(response); // parses HTTP Response
}
```

If I execute the RestUtility call to this API endpoint synchronously elsewhere in the code, it responds just fine, and quickly to boot. But invoking it in this block deadlocks the execution.

I know I'm messing up something with handling asynchronous calls here, but I can't figure out what.

Thanks.

Comment: First things first, you should be using `Task.WhenAll(...)`, not `Task.WaitAll(...)`. In your RestUtility Execute method, there is no need to use Task.Run(...) as it is written. Since you are using `HttpClient.SendAsync(...).Result`, that entire block is executing synchronously anyway and the Task.Run(...) is just extra overhead for no gain. Side note, is there a reason you're not using async/await?

Comment: @MatthewBrubaker No reason, I'm just not familiar with it and part of this (especifically, the RestUtility class) is legacy code.